# ¿Por qué no puedo acceder a mi sitio web por medio de mi dominio?

Tags: debian

Cree una máquina virtual Debian en Citrix XenServer para alojar mis sitios web. El problema es que no puedo acceder a la página web que subí a esa máquina por medio del dominio que le asigné, pero si puedo acceder a ella por medio de la IP. Ya tengo otras máquinas con aplicaciones instaladas y no me había pasado esto. ¿Saben qué pueda estar mal?

Por IP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por dominio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano amigos.

Comment: Revisa la configuración del DNS porque ese dominio no resuelve a ninguna IP.